# How would you train a large number of heroes to work in unison with other heroes they have never met and/or interacted with before?

Tags: super-powers

In a world much like our own, for seemingly no reason, people started developing superpowers through means no one knows how. Each power is different from the last, with some people having similarities between their powers, like two people who can control fire but only one person can make their flames blue that has esoteric effects, or have advantages over the other, like a person with electricity against a person who can turn their entire body into water. The world of comic books seems to have become a reality, heroes fighting against villains in epic battles, but with some key differences.

For one, most heroes are registered with a new branch of the government that acts as a sort of pseudo-military organization designed specifically to deal with these new superhumans, who are trained in ways to use their abilities to their full potential as well as armed/unarmed combat. Villains, meanwhile, are usually acting on orders for various criminal syndicates/organizations, and are willing to do anything to achieve their goals. There are also “solo” villains who range from absolutely insane and who do not care for human life to incredibly goofy but still dangerously competent. In essence, every villain out there that are no longer considered new is a threat, and it’s up to the heroes to stop them whenever they appear.

The problem is that sometimes, a villain is too strong, or has too many allies with various powers that the hero team stationed in whatever town or city they’re fighting in are a bad matchup for them. So, they can all in reinforcements, normally heroes from separate teams that have never interacted with the team in need of aid, and are people with a variety of powers that may or may not be a help or a hindrance to their backup. Not to mention how said heroes' personalities and egos might clash with the others, creating further conflict and it might make it even more difficult to defeat whatever bad guy decided to take the mayor hostage for the umpteenth time. Which is something that the people in charge of these heroes have realized by now, and so wish to try and nip this problem in the bud during the heroes training before it might become an actual problem.

So, without the aid of other powers, how could one train a large number of heroes to work/synergize with other hero teams who they have never met?

Comment: You answered your own question, if you want them to be able to cooperate like the military train them like the military.

Comment: Being taught the science behind how their powers will react with other powers, If they know their power will amplify another power or react in a specific way they can instantly know how to partner with any style.

Comment: @RandySavage That depends on how closely the powers feel like obeying the laws of physics. Most comic-book superheroes have a tendency pick and choose the laws they want. I once read a Spiderman/Ms. Marvel crossover which relied on the Square-Cube Law to beat the villain-of-the-week and completely ignored Conservation of Mass.

Comment: How can this *not* be story-based (and therefore off-topic)? What rules of your world are you talking about? How is training a group of superheros to work together any different than training a group of, say, engineers to work together in an office today? Story-based questions are those that can't be answered without knowing exactly what the story is - and since this site is about building worlds and not telling stories (see [help]).... Can you rewrite this question in terms of the rules of your world (not the characters of your world)?

Comment: actually you can never train for a crisis, training helps you to identify you weakness and cover it... erm... ah! ask someone else to compensate.

Comment: one thing for sure, since this is under the government management, they need to be disciplined, and willingly abide to the laws and role they are tasked with. so they may or may not allowed to kill the villain or criminal on the spot, though i dont know how they gonna deal with public perspective regarding certain role as the true hero and the other is just side kick or look down on to unpopular or passive role. which can create jealousy or rift in the team. considering hero is usually a term for public propaganda which related to popularity job, compare to pragmatic super soldier and such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Think like a MMORPG**

There are quite a few similarities between this situation and large scale raids done on MMORPGs. Both involve large scale teams with superpowers working together to defeat groups of mobs or a single large opponent that can't be done without teamwork. And both are far better done when you have a team which is trained and can cooperate well but *technically* can be accomplished by a group of strangers who have never met before. What's the secret? *Role division*.

In an MMORPG raid, the tank knows that it's the tank and will only be the tank. The ranged damage-dealer knows it's the ranged damage-dealer and won't screw that up. Same goes for the healers, the buffers, those who are responsible for AoE abilities or crowd control. Whole lot of jargon. The point is - everyone knows beforehand what they're supposed to do.

So the way to have a superhero team cooperate is to create roles and assign them out. That way everyone knows *exactly* what they're supposed to do and what everyone else is supposed to do. Someone can use force fields? Great - he's now a 'Protector' type. Someone can generate wide swaths of fire - she's now an 'Destructive' type, specializing in area of effect. When going up against large groups, there will be field leaders who will go over all  the roles beforehand and coordinate with the group. You don't need to know all the ins and outs of someone's power to understand the specific role they'll play.

Answer (score 4):

**With Classifications and Standardized Training**

This very question is answered in [Drew Hayes](http://www.drewhayesnovels.com/)' Super Powereds series.

[image]

Every hero is different but fits into a general category (of their choosing) and then receives training (and has to pass) for said category before becoming a licenced hero.

Heroes need to be licenced to be covered for legal immunity for harm and damage. They need to pass a four year course where only a handful get passed. They then receive a stipend as well as government support for being on call to handle emergencies.

Since the classifications and training is standard, you have an idea of what a person is capable of if not sure exactly what they can do. You want a heavy hitter, you might get a strong man or a guy that can turn into a giant rock monster but either way he hits hard and can take a hit.

Some heroes work in teams but Control can pick and choose the right heroes for a mission and everyone knows what's expected of their role.

Comment: Wildbow's web serials *Worm* and *Ward* also follow the idea of classification.  Classification is more a case of finding a general description for powers though, not a proscriptive exercise, and many heroes' abilities cover more than one area.  Training is very non-standard too, since only the heroes have any kind of formal organisation, and the abilities of every hero are different.  I was tempted to make this a separate answer, but I think it's close enough to yours that you could probably improve your answer by adding *Worm* as another supporting example.

Comment: I could except I've never read that series so I can't comment on it as I don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

Drill them in advance.  In a military style manner, since they are to act together.

In particular, have specialist strike teams that are trained to work together.  Your average hero probably has some drill time each month (week?) dedicated to working in teams for the rare occasions where everyone really is needed, but mostly heroes are slotted into "solo" vs. "team" and trained for that skill set.